# jQuery preventDefault according to a :hover state on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, preventdefault

Please help me to figure out how to handle the situation. We have a link. There is :hover css rule for that link that expands an additional block of links.

```js
$('li').children('a').on('click', function(e) {
 
  if ( $(this).siblings('div').is(':hidden') ) {
  
   e.preventDefault();
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

a {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

li:hover div {
  display: block;
}

li div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="google.com">Google</a>
    <div>
      <a href="gmail.com">GMail</a>
      <a href="maps.google.com">Maps</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The idea: Need to preventDefault for the first link until the additional links expanded. On desktop you won't spot the difference (if only you remove the :hover CSS rule, and try to click on the first link, it won't work since the rest links are hidden). Right behavior: User hovers first link, sees the others, and after that he is able to click on the first link.

The problem starts on mobiles since hover and click are the same. When user clicks on the first link, it will perform href, even though the additional links were hidden at the moment of clicking. But since the :hover rule applies at the same time of clicking on the link, JS treat it as if links were already opened and doesn't prevent default. Means my current IF statement is FALSE on mobile devices a second before actual click. Please help me to find the right approach.

**A solution without using jquery-mobile is warmly welcomed!** Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution: Always run `preventDefault`. And base on the visibility of the div, decide to show the links or go to the href.

```js
$('li').children('a').on('click', function(e) {
 
  e.preventDefault();
  var $links = $(this).siblings('div');
  
  if ($links.is(':hidden')) {
    $links.show();
  } else {
    window.location.href = this.href;
  }
   
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

a {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

li:hover div {
  display: block;
}

li div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="google.com">Google</a>
    <div>
      <a href="gmail.com">GMail</a>
      <a href="maps.google.com">Maps</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

PS: It is more likely to be a user experience problem to me. On touch devices, we don't really have `hover` event. Therefore it is hard to provide same experience as desktop. Usually there would be a slightly different design on mobile devices, like a dropdown menu toggles on `tap` or `touchstart` events in this case.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately on mobile devices your code will have the same issue. When user click / tap on a first link, href will be performed. That's why I was trying to avoid. On PC it works perfectly. But cell phone performs ":hover" before the JS check if it's hidden. So for JS it's ":visible" right after first touch.

Comment: Interesting. The code is working on my cell phone. When tapping on the first link, it displays the additional links and stay on the page. But if it doesn't work on your test device, there is a work around to put `href` into another attribute. For example: using `<a href="void:0" data-href="google.com">Google</a>` in html, and in js use `window.location.href = $(this).data("href");`

Comment: Same. The problem is not in href, the problem is that when it comes to JS to check whether DIV hidden or not, on mobile devices it's getting "visible"  upon click but before JS catch click event, so the JS performs ELSE statement. You can see it in Google Chrome mobile emulation mode, try iPhone 6 for example.